# How to force write locally ONLY even when connected to the internet? Firestore Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, offline

I am making a register application that has 1000+ units per register. I am making changes to a unit one at a time. I don't want those changes to be written to Firebase immediately.

Instead, I want to prompt the user to manually update the documents once a day. (Internet is expensive in my country.)

So the user will have an internet connection but the changes should reflect locally only with a 'queued to upload' tag.

Can this be achieved?

I am using Dart together with Flutter for Android

```
CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> collection =
    instance.collection('tasks');

collection.doc('docID').update({data});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable network access for the Firestore client by [calling `disableNetwork()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FirebaseFirestore/disableNetwork.html):

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.disableNetwork();
```

Then call `enableNetwork()` to re-enable its network access and sync any pending writes (and to synchronize any active listeners).

Also see the Firebase documentation on [disabling and enabling network access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#disable_and_enable_network_access).